# Month End Date of previous month without JODA

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have a date from the request, say 15-aug-2014, How do I calculate the previous month end date (It will be 31-Jul-2014) in java using java,lang.Calendar. We dont use JODA time.

Comment: You can use the GregorianCalendar constructor.

Comment: It tends to be easier to use an inclusive start date and exclusive end date so the end date can have hour/minute/second/etc set to zero.

Comment: Well there are 1 really simple solutions. 1) Start using JODA. 2) Upgrade to Java 8. While there may be political objections to the former, it's a lot harder to argue against the later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
   c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)));
```

Comment: Can we do it using java.lang.Date as well?

Comment: @Agasthya No only the calendar can add Date. But after you have called the add function you gan call c.getTime() and you have a java.util.Date.

Comment: ok thanks.. How can we check if the date is not a month end date and then then do the above mentioned logic?

Comment: To keep it simple how can we check if a day is a month end or not?

Comment: @Agasthya I would add one day to the date you have and looks if the month is the same for both dates

Comment: cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); gives me the maximum date which i can compare with the current day

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help,

```
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   //Set the Calendar date to 1st of the current month
   cal.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
   // Subtract a day from it
   cal.set(Calendar.DATE,cal.get(Calendar.DATE)-1);
   // Prints the previous month end date
   System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

From the `Calendar` instance, you can get the `Date` by

```
Date date = cal.getTime();
```

Finally, you can use `SimpledateFormat` to format your date as needed

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
System.out.println( "The date is: "+  sdf.format(date));
```

Hope, it helps!

Comment: Can we do the same using javal.lang.Date as well?

Comment: @Agasthya There is no `java.lang.Date` API actually. But, you have `java.util.Date`. But, it will not be a good idea to do this operations with it.